# How to call an enum from another class?

Tags: grails, enums

I am currently working on a grails project. I've created an enum located on a certain project folder, and wanted to access it from a class located on another project folder.
My enum looks something like this:

```
public enum Options {  


OPTION_1("Option_1"),
OPTION_2("Option_2"),
OPTION_3("Option_3");

final String option;

Options(String option) {
    this.option = option;
}
```

}

Now, I am having a problem in calling that enum from a certain class in my application. For example:

```
Response{
option = new Option.OPTION_1("Option_1") //not sure on how to call an enum
}
```

But what I wanted to do here is to assign the enum to the property option in the Response {} section..

How will I properly do that?
Help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enums are predefined objects, it will have a private constructor, You can not create a new instance with new. You just need to call Option.OPTION_1;

```
Response{
option = Option.OPTION_1; 
}
```

Comment: @ Rp- : your comment said not to use new. But the code had. I removed the 'new'. Hope that is fine.

Comment: Yeah.. Copied the code from OP's question, Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 4):

You just need to reference it as `Options.OPTION_1` there's no new on enums.

```
Option option = Options.OPTION_1;
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot instantiate an enum object, the only instances that are there are defined by you in the enum class.

So the correct way is:

```
Response {
    option = Options.OPTION_1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a new instance of an enum. There is no need to because it can hold only fixed number of values. So `option = new Option.OPTION_1("Option_1")` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Should work.

```
Response{
def option = Option.OPTION_1;
}
```

related link [Enums in groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Enums)

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of the grails part in this, but your usage of `enum` seems to be incorrect

If you have an enum as

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

You can access individual value using `Day.MONDAY`, `Day.SUNDAY`, etc.

Please check the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: I think grails and java do same way in declaring enums, since grails is based in java..